# How to concatenate string and integer in if condition in tableau

Tags: concatenation, aggregation, tableau-api

I am trying to concatenate country with its rank based on sales in if condition  like

```
IF [TOP 20 COUNTRIES]  THEN [COUNTRY]+[RANK] ELSE "OTHERS"
```

here I am getting error saying  can not mix aggregate and non aggregate fields in if condition. then I tried like

```
IF ATTR( [TOP 20 COUNTRIES] ) THEN ATTR([COUNTRY])+[RANK] ELSE "OTHERS"
```

then also I am getting error saying Boolean can not aggregate.

Here `[TOP 20 COUNTRIES]`  is SET of Top 20 countries based on SALES

please help me in this

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too an u can accept it too

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to mix aggregated arguments (e.g., sum, count) with non aggregate ones (e.g., any field directly). And that's what you're doing mixing aggregated arguments non aggregate ones.When creating a calculated field, you may see a “Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate arguments to function” error message. This message displays when a calculation contains a mix of disaggregated values and aggregated values.  Aggregations allow you to look at numerical data in some sort of summary form, such as sum and average.